# Engineyard rollback - does it rollback migrations as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am new to Enginyard. I have deployed the application using enginyard web interface but rollback from console using "ey rollback" command.

My question is is this command also rollback the migrations or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [engineyard-serverside API](https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard-serverside/blob/master/lib/engineyard-serverside/deploy.rb), it doesn't rollback migrations.  This makes sense given how unpredictable that can be. For reference, the actual code which does the migration is:

```
  # task
  def rollback
    if c.all_releases.size > 1
      rolled_back_release = c.latest_release
      c.release_path = c.previous_release(rolled_back_release)

      revision = File.read(File.join(c.release_path, 'REVISION')).strip
      info "~> Rolling back to previous release: #{short_log_message(revision)}"

      run_with_callbacks(:symlink)
      sudo "rm -rf #{rolled_back_release}"
      bundle
      info "~> Restarting with previous release"
      with_maintenance_page { run_with_callbacks(:restart) }
    else
      info "~> Already at oldest release, nothing to roll back to"
      exit(1)
    end
  end
```

You can fairly easily parse that out to mean that it re-does the symlink for your project, removes the newest (failed) deployment, and restarts the webserver.